# Python 2 class inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm new to programming and I've got a question about inheritance and creating classes. I've got a class "Obstacle", of which there are types such as cylinders and walls (which are coded as cylinder(Obstacle) etc.). I want to make a class for "barriers" which are essentially a type of wall but I want the agent to interact differently with them as they would to walls. My wall class has different variables defined within its initializing method/function and I'm confused as to what I have to specify when I create barrier(Wall) - do I have to copy until barrier(Wall) all of the x1 = and so on, or will those be copied over automatically.

Below I've included a bit of what is in the wall class (not everything), but just to show what I mean by variables defined in the first method.

```
class Wall(Obstacle):
""" Class representing a Wall obstacle. """

    def __init__(self, origin, end, detection=9.):
        self.type = 'wall'
        self.origin = origin
        self.end = end
        self.detection = detection

        x1 = self.origin[0]
        y1 = self.origin[1]
        x2 = self.end[0]
        y2 = self.end[1]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Wall obstacle"
```

Comment: dunder str is not indented correctly (as it is now it's not part of class Wall).

Comment: yes sorry thank you! Had some indentation issues when I copied it over! @narn

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you shouldn't copy any variables to the child class, your variables will be inherited. Class variables will be the same and you will be able to set Instance variables during instantiation of child. Consider this code:

```
class Test1():
    test2 = 'lol2'  # class variable shared by all instances

    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test  # instance variable unique to each instance
        test3 = self.test  # just useless variable not assigned to class or instance


class Test2(Test1):
    pass


t = Test2('lol')
print(t.test)  # lol
print(t.test2)  # lol2
print(dir(t))  # ['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'test', 'test2']

t = Test2('foo')
print(t.test)  # foo
print(t.test2)  # lol2
print(dir(t))  # ['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'test', 'test2']
```

so I think you should do something like:

```
class Wall(Obstacle):

    def __init__(self, _type, origin, end, detection=9.):
        self.type = _type
        self.origin = origin
        self.end = end
        self.detection = detection

        self.x1 = self.origin[0]
        self.y1 = self.origin[1]
        self.x2 = self.end[0]
        self.y2 = self.end[1]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Wall obstacle"


class Barrier(Wall):

    def __str__(self):
        return "Barrier obstacle"


_type = 'barrier'
origin = ...
end = ... 
detection = ...

bar = Barrier(_type, origin, end, detection)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ... do I have to copy ... all of the x1 = and so on, or will those be copied over automatically

The Vars `x1, y1, x2, y2` are `temporary local` to `self.__init__` and are **lost** after Return.

That Vars are not needed at all, implement a `property def coordinate(...`

```
class Wall(Obstacle):
    ...

    @property
    def coordinate(self):
        return (self.origin[0], self.origin[1], self.end[0], self.end[1])
```

**Usage**:

```
wall = Wall((1,2),(1,2) )
x1, y1, x2, y2 = wall.coordinate
```